# VMWare for 32-bit?

Tags: windows, vmware, 32-bit

I want to run VMWare for Windows and I tried to install VMWare 11, but it seems to only work on 64-bit.  Where can I find the 32-bit version installer?

Comment: There isn't one.  **VMWare 11 is 64-bit only.**

Comment: why don't use 64-bit windows? In 32-bit windows you might not even have enough memory for one or more virtual machines

Answer (score 4):

First of all VMWare is a brand, not a product. Given that you added the number 11 to it I assume that you are looking for VMware Workstation 11 (and not for ESX or Player).

The latest is not available for 32 bit systems, probably because it no longer makes sense to use Workstation (more expensive than VMWare Player and thus only interesting if you want to run multiple VMs at the same time. Something which Player does not do) on a system which is limited in memory.

Which means it is probably uneconomical to create, maintain and support.

Add to that that almost everybody uses 64-bit version of Windows (at least in the last decade) except for some very low power systems (tablet, netbooks, ...) on which you probably do not want to run multiple VMs anyway.

So to recap: It makes little [economical] sense and thus VMware simply did not create a 32-bit version.

Comment: My 3 year old netbook is 64-bit and it's so slow it's almost useless now. But it still runs virtual machines. At this point any 32-bit-only netbook is probably too old to bother with.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not have a 64-bit processor and/or a 64-bit operating system, you can still run VMWare Workstation 10 and/or VMWare Player 6.0.

Alternatives are also Oracle VirtualBox which do still distribute a 32-bit binary and Windows Virtual PC.